# Solution to export subscribers who selected various field opt-outs, through query or other method in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am looking for a solution to export subscribers who selected various field opt-outs, through query or other method in salesforce marketing cloud. For example, some subscribers have opted into receiving emails from some locations (designated fields) and not all. This export is being run through alteryx and a master database and into a new Email Service Provider. Retaining the opt outs are crucial. Looking for some help with this migration as I am not an expert at salesforce marketing cloud. Thank you!

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud), [sql](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on salesforce.stackexchange.com